# Position UIButton next to UIView title

Tags: ios, swift

The Health App on IOS has a "user account" button next to each tab.

[image]

I would like to replicate this behavior. However, my code pushes the button above the title.

[image]

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MyTabController : UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        viewControllers = [createNavController(for: UIViewController(), title: NSLocalizedString("Summary", comment: ""), image: UIImage(systemName: "suit.heart.fill")!)]
    }

    internal func createNavController(for rootViewController: UIViewController, title: String, image: UIImage) -> UIViewController {
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
        navController.tabBarItem.title = title
        navController.tabBarItem.image = image
        navController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        rootViewController.title = title
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem()
        barButton.image = UIImage(systemName: "person.circle")
        rootViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
        return navController
    }
}
```

I know I can manually [add a button with a label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676368/uinavigationbar-with-buttons-as-title) and push it "down", but it seems overkill for something so simple. What is an efficient way to reproduce this behavior? ( without introducing any static constants )

Comment: check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062176/image-for-navigation-bar-with-large-title-ios-11)

Comment: @VisalRajapakse good catch. Not a fan of the magic constants they are using, but it is an available solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image for Navigation Bar with Large Title iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062176/image-for-navigation-bar-with-large-title-ios-11)

Comment: @JoRa negative, since the author uses contants. I was hoping there was a way without doing so.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to scroll this slowly, you will see following.

`Health.app` setup does not seem like a standard `UINavigationBar` / `UIBarButtonItem` setup.
[image]

`Contacts.app` shows what it looks like with a standard `UINavigationBar` / `UIBarButtonItem` setup.
[image]

Add your own `UIView` below navigation bar, keeping the navigation title / bar button items empty. Track the scroll state and update your own view and navigationBar's appearances as needed.